# Why doesn't bootstrap detect the toggle-modal on a selected option?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using the modal with links and it works as expected:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-multiple-70304842829540" data-remote="true" data-type="html" data-method="post" title="Edit Multiple" href="/contacts/edit_multiple">
  <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-multiple-70304842829540" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sizer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="overflow: auto;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Multiple</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
        <img src="/assets/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-target">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I click on link and modal displays. However, I try this with an option element of a select form and the modal does not display:

```
<select name="global_filter_id" id="global_filter_id" data-remote="true" data-url="/contacts" data-params="card_position=card&amp;contactable=Lead" data-type="html" class="form-control">
  <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="filterEdit" data-url="/contacts/edit_multiple" data-remote="true" data-type="html" data-method="post" data-params="filterable_type=Lead" value="1">Edit/Delete Filter</option>
</select>
<div class="modal fade" id="filterEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sizer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="overflow: auto;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit/Delete Filter</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
        <img src="/assets/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-target">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the option element has the data-toggle='modal' attribute and the data-target of the option element matches the id of the modal div. So why doesn't the modal display when I select the option element?

Comment: I added a script to open it programatically. But you need to have at least one more option, so you trigger the `change` event. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is listening to `click` and `tap` events to trigger the opening of modal.

But `<option>`s are invalid targets for both events. As you can test below, they never happen:

```js
$(window).on('click tap','option', function(e){
  console.log('This will never happen!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

All `pointer` and `touch` events are off on `<option>`s. The only one that triggers is `change`, but on the parent `<select>`.

For more details about this, see [2]nd point under [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Browser_compatibility) on MDN.

---

A workaround would be to get the modal data from the selected option and open the modal yourself. Looking closer, I noticed the `data` params on your bootstrap toggle look like params of an XhrHttpRequest. You're going to make that call yourself using params from data and parse the values in the modal on success. For now I just `console.log()`-ed them:

```js
$('#global_filter_id').on('change', function(e){
  let data = $(e.target).find('option:selected').data();

  if (data && (data.toggle=="modal") && $('#'+data.target).is('.modal')) {

    console.log(data); 
    // make your ajax call here and open the modal
    // while waiting for results...

    $('#'+data.target).modal();
  } 
})
```

```js
$('#global_filter_id').on('change', function(e){
  let data = $(e.target).find('option:selected').data();
  
  if (data && (data.toggle=="modal") && $('#'+data.target).is('.modal')) {

    console.log(data); 
    // make your ajax call here and open the modal
    // while waiting for results...

    $('#'+data.target).modal();
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<select name="global_filter_id" id="global_filter_id" data-remote="true" data-url="/contacts" data-params="card_position=card&amp;contactable=Lead" data-type="html" class="form-control">
  <option></option>
  <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="filterEdit" data-url="/contacts/edit_multiple" data-remote="true" data-type="html" data-method="post" data-params="filterable_type=Lead" value="1">Edit/Delete Filter</option>
</select>
<div class="modal fade" id="filterEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sizer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="overflow: auto;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit/Delete Filter</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
        <img src="/assets/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-target">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, you are using some EcmaScript 6 in that solution with let.

Comment: Use `var`. `let` will `let` Apple mobile devices below iOS 10 down, as well as  Konqueror 4.14.  [`Compat table here`](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).